# Filter list using another list?

Tags: f#

I have two list of

```
type Item1 = { Id: int; .... }
type Item2 = { Id: int; .... }
let list1: Item1 list = ....
let list2: Item2 list = ....
```

I need to filter `list1` which `Id` exists in `list2`. The following code doesn't work.

```
list1 |> Seq.filter (fun l1 -> (List.exists (fun l2 -> l1.Id = l2.Id) list2))
```

It expects list2 to have the type of `Item1 list`. However, the following code works.

```
list1 |> Seq.filter (fun l1 -> (list2 |> List.exists (fun l2 -> l1.Id = l2.Id) ))
```

Why? Aren't they just two different ways to write the code with the same functionality?

Comment: Interestingly, both of these actually compile fine for me on F# 3.0, although I wouldn't have expected them to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# type inference is strictly left to right.  As a result, in this part

```
 list1 |> Seq.filter (fun l1 -> (List.exists (fun l2 -> l1.Id = l2.Id) list2))
```

the type of `l2` is not known.  As a result you get a (slightly weird) error message.

In the second case, you have `list2 |> ...` which means that the type of `l2` is known when you do the comparison, so everything is fine.

Comment: If the type of `list2` is known, but should work. Only if is a parameter of a function without any type annotation and that function is still not used anywhere on the rest of the file will this fail to typecheck